# Match text in a row to text in a column

Tags: excel-formula

[Picture of Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRars.png)
[Copy of Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1whIEnaPwj17S7VP3ymcuy1fH7lHcY7VS/view?usp=sharing)

I am trying to make a animal compatibility chart for a game.  Along the left side and running across the top are the listing of animals.  Each animal will have a separate sheet in excel listing which animals they are compatible with.  Each sheet will be named the same way as in the column on left.  My goal is to have excel search through the appropriate sheet (Named for each animal) and place an X in the cell that intersects with an animal from the top row, thus marking a compatible animal.  I have a feeling that index and/or match is the way to go but I am not well versed.  Thank You in advanced for any help
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for `INDEX MATCH`. You should provide some sample data, to get better answers.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am new to this forum, I wanted to input a copy of my sheet but didnt figure how.  I will try to edit this.  Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my comment and based on that, your feeling, were wrong, though it made me laugh, thanks for that :). Enter

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-1)&"'!A1:A1000"),RIGHT(B$1,LEN(B$1)-1))>0,"X","")
```

in `B2` and drag downwards and sideways. You need to get rid of the apostrophes in `Bairds Tapir` and  `Thomsons Gazelle`, if you want the function to work on these lines too.

The errors indicate missing sheets.

Comment: WOW!! Thank You so much, this is exactly what I needed.  I also added the IFERROR function in front of the entire thing and was able to clear out the errors.  I think I will expand on this some more with formatting and color coding to make it visually appealing.  Thanks